# Chrome doesn't properly display YouTube video pages

Tags: youtube, google-chrome

Since a couple of days ago, I can't properly load a YouTube video page on Chrome (both on my office computer and my home computer).

It loads only the video panel with no other panels (description, comments, other videos etc.). Moreover, at first it doesnt load the video:

[image: First upload]

and the page needs to be refreshed to get this:

[image: After refreshing]

The video itself is playing fine.

Couldn't find a fix just yet.

Comment: Close voters: This question is about the interaction of a specific web application with a web browser. As such, it _is_ on-topic here.

Comment: This belongs more to IT that webapps. http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/4a/4a102f0529cd0acddfa88a8dea431001d8e671f9def8ecaa6992bc455cee56f4.jpg